# VS 2012 Cannot generate dependency graph due to apostrophe

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I've inherited an existing project for which I'm trying to generate some useful documentation- at this point, a dependency graph.  It's a Visual Studio project, so I'd like to take advantage of the built-in architecture and analysis tools.

Unfortunately, the graph generator isn't working.  Apparently it uses SQLServer Express on the back end.  I'm blessed to be Irish, with an apostrophe in my name.  Punctuation inside names has never occurred to the Visual Studio team, so the dependency database creation fails due to a parse error- it's treating the apostrophe as a string delimiter.

I'm not quite sure why my real name matters to creating this graph.  Nor am I sure how to change it for just this purpose.  I certainly don't want to rename myself.  Is there a hack around this problem?  The error screen mentions "Open the XML Editor to fix these errors", but that just presents an unpopulated XML structure.

The exact error (name redacted):

Invalid usage of the option (NAME AFTER APOSTROPHE) in the CREATE/ALTER DATABASE statement.

Call Stack:
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)

at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.Repository.SqlInteraction.InternalExecuteBatch(SqlConnection connection, SqlTransaction transaction, String script, Int32 timeoutInSec)
   at Microsoft.Repository.SqlInteraction.<>c_*DisplayClass16.b*_15()
   at Microsoft.Repository.SqlInteraction.ExecuteRepositoryAction(Action action)
   at Microsoft.Repository.SqlInteraction.ExecuteBatch(SqlConnection connection, SqlTransaction transaction, String script, Int32 timeoutInSec)
   at Microsoft.Repository.DatabaseCreator.CreateEmptyDatabase(SqlConnection masterConnection)
   at Microsoft.Repository.RenamingDatabaseCreator.CreateEmptyDatabase(SqlConnection masterConnection)
   at Microsoft.Repository.DatabaseCreator.b_*0(SqlConnection masterConn)
   at Microsoft.Repository.SqlInteraction.<>c*_DisplayClass9.b__7()
   at Microsoft.Repository.SqlInteraction.ExecuteRepositoryAction(Action action)
   at Microsoft.Repository.SqlInteraction.UsingConnection(SqlConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act)
   at Microsoft.Repository.SqlInteraction.UsingMasterConnection(String connectionString, Action`1 act)
at Microsoft.Repository.DatabaseCreator.Microsoft.Repository.IDatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Progression.CacheUtilities.InternalCreateCache(String cacheConnectionString, String localCacheDirectory, ActionContext context)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Progression.CacheUtilities.EnsureCacheExists(String cacheConnectionString, String localCacheDirectory, ActionContext context)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ArchitectureTools.ProgressiveReveal.CheckSizeThenPopulateCommand.Execute(ActionContext context, IGraphStatus statusReporter, IProgressionCacheSettings settings)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ArchitectureTools.ProgressiveReveal.ProgressiveRevealProvider.PopulateCodeRepositoryHandler(ActionContext context)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Progression.ActionManager.CallNormalActions(Action action, ActionContext actionContext)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Progression.ActionManager.InternalExecuteAction(Object context)